# Spring boot create custom decorator to add field and ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, decorator

In my project i created two mappedSuperclass.
One called Base Entity where i have 4 common field (creationUser,updateUser, creationTime and updateTime) plus the logic to update the field on update end persist. And another one called BaseAccessoryEntity that i use for all those table that have the same structure.
There is a way  to create a decorator that can i use for all my class instead of extend the baseclass?